# Error: 'textureID' is a private member of 'Texture'

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut

What is the solution to the error, "textureID is a private member of Texture." Texture is a class and textureID is an unsigned integer. The image the program is running is a 24-bit uncompressed bitmap (I think). The error appears at glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->textureID). Below is part of the code.

```
    void display() {
    preProcessEvents();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Camera Transformations
    glRotatef(Camera::rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(Camera::rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(Camera::rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-Camera::position.x, -Camera::position.y, -Camera::position.z);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-1, 0, -3);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0, 2, -3);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1, 0, -3);
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->textureID);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

    glTexCoord2f(100, 100);
    glVertex3f(100, 0, 100);

    glTexCoord2f(-100, 100);
    glVertex3f(-100, 0, 100);

    glTexCoord2f(-100, -100);
    glVertex3f(-100, 0, -100);

    glTexCoord2f(100, -100);
    glVertex3f(100, 0, -100);

    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

The class is located in a header file and the code is below. Should 'unsigned int textureID' be under public or something? Could this be why the error says textureID is private?

```
    #ifndef __Xcode_Glut_Tutorial__Texture__
    #define __Xcode_Glut_Tutorial__Texture__

    #include <iostream>
    #include <OpenGL/gl.h>

    using namespace std;

    class Texture {
        unsigned int textureID;
    public:
        Texture(void* data, int w, int h, int format);

        static Texture* loadBMP(const char* filename);
    };



    #endif /* defined(__Xcode_Glut_Tutorial__Texture__) */
```

Comment: Well it's private so you can't access it like that, either make it public or add a getter function if you're just interested in the value

Comment: By default, the access specification in a class is private.  Since you haven't made the variable public, it isn't.

Comment: I tried making 'unsigned int textureID' public by declaring it under public. I get a 'Build Succeeded'. However, on the left hand side of the screen I get several threads that have breakpoints in the program. Perhaps I declared the 'unsigned int textureID' in the incorrect manner?

Answer (score 0):

`textureID` is private in `Texture` class
**solution 1:**
you must change:

```
class Texture {
    unsigned int textureID;
public:
    Texture(void* data, int w, int h, int format);

    static Texture* loadBMP(const char* filename);
};
```

to

```
class Texture {
public:
    unsigned int textureID;

    Texture(void* data, int w, int h, int format);

    static Texture* loadBMP(const char* filename);
};
```

**solution 2:**
using public getter function :

```
class Texture {
    unsigned int textureID;
public:
    Texture(void* data, int w, int h, int format);

    static Texture* loadBMP(const char* filename);
    unsigned int get_textureID()
    {
        return textureID;
    }
};
```

And :

```
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->get_textureID());
```

Comment: tried both solutions. got 'Build Succeeded' for both. Received a bunch of threads on the left hand side. There must be something else to this. I'll keep thinking about it.